# stretch button horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a relative layout in which I would like to align one image button and 2 normal buttons horizontally
What I would like to do is once I switch my layout to landscape mode, I would like the two normal buttons stretched horizontally in an equal width.

portrait mode

```
-----------------------------
ImageBtn  [Button1] [Button2]
-----------------------------
```

Landscape mode

```
-----------------------------------------------
ImageBtn  [     Button1    ] [     Button2    ]
-----------------------------------------------
```

I don't know a beauty design approach to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create 2 layout files for this to work, one in the normal layout directory, one in  the layout-land directory.

The normal layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#FFFF0000"
    android:text="btn2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:background="#FF00FF00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn2"
    android:text="btn1" />

<ImageButton
    android:background="#FF0000FF"
    android:id="@+id/ibtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The landscape layout (in layout-land directory):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="3" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF0000FF"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FF00FF00"
    android:text="btn1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFF0000"
    android:text="btn2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all 3 buttons in a `LinearLayout`, then assign `Button1` and `Button2` the same value for `layout_weight`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple i will give the layout You just use this for your layout....
Here i used 3 button you just replace one into image button...that's all...All the best

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="@drawable/logo">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

 </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use weight in layout design.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <ImageButton android:layout_width="0dp" 
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_weight="1"/>

         <TextView    android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_weight="1"/>

         <TextView    android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This would cause the `ImageButton` to stretch too.